# [Snowflake]: How to create table dynamically from JSON properties

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have activity events from PowerBI event logs and there are multiple types of event activities, and for each activity type the log contains different properties, e.g.

```json
[{ "Activity": "ViewReport", "ReportID": "aaa-bbb-ccc", "WorkspaceID": "eee-fff-ddd"},
 { "Activity": "DatasetRefresh", "DatasetID": "...", "IsSuccess": true}]
```

(in reality there is around 60 types each with around 20 properties).
I want to be able to create as many tables as there is event types and to each table to contain the properties from JSON.

now I'd like to have a proc/sql that will create the table":

- `Activity_Report_View` with all the props `ReportID`, `WroskpaceID`,
- `Activity_Dataset_Refresh` with props `DatasetId`, `IsSuccess`

And this needs to be dynamic without me having to list out all the columns manually, something like this (which obviously is not working):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ACTIVITY_REPORT_VIEW AS 
  SELECT
    d.JSON_DATA:*
  FROM JSON_TEMP d
  WHERE d.JSON_DATA:Activity = 'ViewReport'
  ORDER BY d.JSON_DATA:CreationTime DESC;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the full solution for you, but have you considered creating a stored procedure for this?  I believe you could execute something like this.

```
SELECT KEY AS COLUMN_NAME
        , LISTAGG(DISTINCT(TYPEOF(VALUE)),', ') AS POSSIBLE_DATA_TYPES
FROM
        JSON_TEMP a
        , LATERAL FLATTEN (INPUT => var) b
GROUP BY 1;
```

Which would give you a list of attributes and possible data types for those attributes.  From this record set, you could dynamically build out a SQL query that has the correct CREATE TABLE statement, including the correct data types for those columns.

This will work if your JSON is a flat structure, but becomes more complicated if you have nested JSON structures.  You can add a `RECURSIVE => TRUE` to the `LATERAL FLATTEN` statement to get all of your attributes, but the corresponding CTAS would be complex.

Comment: Hi @Mike, that's pretty neat, thank you. Played around with it a bit and managed to get the list of the properties, but I think the datatypes are the most tricky part of this solution. I will probably just end up with the DDLs for each event. Thanks again